# How to find iframe with Selenium and Python 3

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, automation

I having trouble with finding some data on [this](https://naturalia.fr/sardines-naturel-95g) page. I need the link of the main image, and the sub images. I also need the text under the 2 tabs "Ingridients et allergens" and "Mode d'empoli et conservation". It seems to me that these are iframes (or the same iframe) but whatever I tried returns an error. Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Here is an example of a non-working code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
link = 'https://naturalia.fr/sardines-naturel-95g'
browser.get(link)

try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="tab-label-ingredients_info-title"]''').click()
    descr = browser.find_element_by_class_name('cms-content')
    print('Description2: {}'.format(descr.text))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    main_img = browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/img''').get_attribute('src')
    print(main_img)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Can you post what exactly you have tried so we can help going from there?

Comment: For example I tried finding the image by class name - "fotorama__stage" or even "fotorama__stage__frame fotorama_vertical_ratio fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img magnify-wheel-loaded fotorama__active". I also tried xpath by using Chrome's "copy XPATH" option - but all of these return an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the image url using the xpath to the `img` tag and then accessing it's `src` attribute:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/img''').get_attribute('src')
'https://naturalia.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/image/368x414/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/3/2/3263670138016.1-0001.jpg'
```

For the text under the tabs, first click on them and then proceed to extract the text finding the class `"cms-content"`:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="tab-label-ingredients_info-title"]''').click()
>>> mytext = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cms-content").text
>>> print(mytext)

Sardines, eau, citron* (pulpe, zeste et jus), sel de mer, thym*, fenouil*, persil*, laurier*.
*3.5% des ingrédients d'origine agricole sont issus de l’agriculture biologique certifié par FR BIO 10
Valeurs nutritionnelles moyennes Pour 100g
Energie 136 Kcal / 572 KJ
Matières grasses 4,9 g
Dont acides gras
(......)
```

You may also use the `class` to extract all the images links:

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fotorama__img")
links = [image.get_attribute('src') for image in images]

>>> links
['https://naturalia.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/image/368x414/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/3/2/3263670138016.1-0001.jpg', 'https://naturalia.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/image/368x414/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/3/2/3263670138016.8-0001.jpg', 'https://naturalia.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/thumbnail/84x84/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/3/2/3263670138016.8-0001.jpg', 'https://naturalia.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/thumbnail/84x84/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/3/2/3263670138016.1-0001.jpg']
```

Comment: For the image, I'm getting this error: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/img.  Also, is it a good idea to use xpath here? I need to do this action for many more pages on this site.

Comment: About the text, I tried the same thing but with find_by_id' - why isn't it working? Also not working with xpath...

Comment: @DavidRotenberg Please try my second solution, using `class`.

Comment: @DavidRotenberg "I tried the same thing but with find_by_id" - You'd have to post the entire code for me to understand why it's not working, otherwise I won't be able to help

Comment: I tired it, not working... I'm using Firefox if that matter

Comment: It works for me, I'm using `ChromeDriver`, but this is also working using `PhantomJS`.

Comment: browser = webdriver.Firefox()
link = 'https://naturalia.fr/sardines-naturel-95g'
browser.get(link)   try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="tab-label-ingredients_info-title"]''').click()
    descr = browser.find_element_by_class_name('cms-content')
    print('Description2: {}'.format(descr.text))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

Comment: Since comments are not really good with `markdown`, It would be better if you could edit your question with your error.

Comment: Try finding the element to click with it's id: `driver.find_element_by_id("tab-label-ingredients_info-title").click()`. Both of them are working to me.

Comment: Aguiar Still not working, maybe you have other suggestions?